# Select rows given 2 columns, if at least one value is below threshold

Tags: python, pandas, select

I have a pandas dataframe

```
NAME    VALUE
  A        2 
  A        1 
  B        4 
  A        3 
  C        2 
  B        8
```

I would like to add a column if values in column "Name" contain AT LEAST ONE value in "Values" below 3, corresponding to the name, such that:

```
NAME    VALUE   BELOW_THRESHOLD
  A        2          Y 
  A        4          Y 
  B        4          N 
  A        3          Y 
  C        2          Y 
  B        8          N
```

Comment: Your two DataFrames are different. The second "A" in the first table has a value of 1, while the second "A" in the second table has a value of 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on `NAME` and `apply` a lambda that tests your condition and take the `max` value which will be `True` if any meet the condition and assign using `map`:

```
In [317]:
df['BELOW_THRESHOLD'] = df['NAME'].map(df.groupby('NAME')['VALUE'].apply(lambda x: (x < 3).max()))
df

Out[317]:
  NAME  VALUE BELOW_THRESHOLD
0    A      2            True
1    A      1            True
2    B      4           False
3    A      3            True
4    C      2            True
5    B      8           False
```

You can convert to `Y` or `N` after using `np.where`:

```
In [318]:
df['BELOW_THRESHOLD'] = np.where(df['BELOW_THRESHOLD'], 'Y','N')
df

Out[318]:
  NAME  VALUE BELOW_THRESHOLD
0    A      2               Y
1    A      1               Y
2    B      4               N
3    A      3               Y
4    C      2               Y
5    B      8               N
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use transform:

```
df.groupby('NAME').transform('min') < 3
Out[47]: 
   VALUE
0   True
1   True
2  False
3   True
4   True
5  False
```

It returns a boolean array so if you need Y/N, you can pass it to np.where like EdChum did.